# Crop the center of an image

Tags: python-imaging-library, python-2.x

How can l use the function `crop()` from `PIL` to crop the center of an image of 224*224.

**Given an input image of :**

320*240, crop the center of this image of dimension 224*224

**Expected output :**

cropped center of the image of dimension 224*224

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with this image where the coloured part is 224x224 on a black background of 320x240.

[image]

I would just use `numpy` to crop like this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Open the image and convert to numpy array
im=Image.open('start.png')
im=np.array(im)

# Work out where top left corner is
y=int((320-224)/2)
x=int((240-224)/2)

# Crop, convert back from numpy to PIL Image and and save
cropped=im[x:x+224,y:y+224]
Image.fromarray(cropped).save('result.png')
```

[image]